# Add "/question/ask" Link at the End of How To Ask Page

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

*First : This is something that came up from discussion with shog9 in the comment section of [this previous topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171378/add-the-questions-ask-magic-link-to-comments).*

After discussing a bit about adding the a magic link to /question/ask, the issue became clearer. The problem is not really that the comments miss the magic link to that page but that the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page misses a section at the end to bring users to the ask page.

When I'm commenting on "Not An Answer" answers, I often include a link to the /questions/ask page, because the how to ask one don't. And this is painful, especially on mobile unit since you can't retrieve the link directly to include it in your comment.

A way to solve that would be to add a section at the end saying something similar to :

> Now that you went through this, you are ready to [ask your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)!

With that simple thing, we could now directly send users to the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page in comment and know that they would have a complete page about how to ask *with* the ask link at the end, so once they are ready to ask they can go. It would make the UX more *fluid* since they don't have to go back up at the end.

As shog said :

> I mean, add a link to /questions/ask at the end of /questions/how-to-ask. Then you have one short link that addresses both

And this is completely true. That would also make the page more complete, Since to get to the end of the page you most likely have to scroll down, and when scrolled you don't have access to the <kbd>Ask Button</kbd> directly.

---

tldr : Add a link to the [ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page at the end of [how to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171378/add-the-questions-ask-magic-link-to-comments) page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [still](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171378/add-the-questions-ask-magic-link-to-comments#comment507330_171378) say no. This simply isn't necessary. The "Ask Question" button is right at the top of How to Ask, and *every other page*.

You indicated in the other question that you're concerned about questions being posted as answers. That should already be covered, too: there's an "ask your own question" link right below the "Post Your Answer" button.

If a user can't find one of these two links for some reason, I don't have a lot of hope for his question.

Also, I think the search box right in the midst of the How to Ask page is a great move. Putting another copy of the "Ask Question" button at the bottom is not only unecessary, it'll just encourage people to skip the search and go right to posting.

Comment: Or maybe doing something like the about page, where the stuff do no appear right away. But when you are at the end of the "How to Ask" there's something missing. It just ends without any conclusion. And maybe not a button as clear as the other but an hyper link (like the other ones in the page) just to end the page.